# how to create composite primary key android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making one android datastorage application.In this my problem is I want to create composite primary key in sqlite table android.I want composite key for two column names.
syntax:

```
public static final String PEN_TABLE_QUERY= " CREATE TABLE if not exists " + PEN_TABLE + "( "+ PEN_ID + " INTEGER  , " + MAIN_CATEGORY + " TEXT , " + SUB_CATEGORY + " TEXT , " + PEN_TYPE + " TEXT , " +  DESC + " TEXT , " + DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY " +")";
```

I want primary key for both id and date please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a composite primary key, you add a table constraint as `PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)`. Your current statement makes the `DATE` columns the primary key. The correct syntax is:

`"CREATE TABLE table_name ([columns definitions...], PRIMARY KEY (column1_name, column2_name));"`

Doc: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: can it be more than 2 columns?